# Is it a good practice use a class to build a object made of other objects?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm using Python/Tkinter to build an app, and came across this "problem":

Let's use this code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Foo():

    def __init__(self, window):

        self.this_frame = Frame(window)

        self.generic_txt_label = Label(self.this_frame, text="Value:")
        self.generic_txt_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        
        self.value_label = Label(self.this_frame, text="0.00")
        self.value_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

        self.this_frame.grid()

root_window = Tk()

bar = Foo(root_window)

root_window.mainloop()
```

the code will produce a frame with two labels inside.
In my app i need 3 of that frame, and i thought that i could do `bar_2 = Foo(root_window)` and `bar_3 = Foo(root_window)`.

Is that a good practice? Using a class to create and put together several objects. If not, how should i do it?

Comment: This sounds like you're asking for opinions, which is off-topic for Stackoverflow. But yes, this is a good practice :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes absolutely, and it's very common. And you are only one short step from another very common practice, which is to subclass an existing tkinter widget to make your own custom widgets. Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

class Foo(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        self.generic_txt_label = Label(self, text="Value:")
        self.generic_txt_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.value_label = Label(self, text="0.00")
        self.value_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

root_window = Tk()
bar = Foo(root_window)
bar.grid()

bar_2 = Foo(root_window)
bar_2.grid()

bar_3 = Foo(root_window)
bar_3.grid()

root_window.mainloop()
```

Now Foo has all the attributes of a tkinter Frame like pack() and grid(), and behaves just like a Frame because it literally is a type of Frame.

Comment: I was thinking just this while waiting for someone to answer, thanks <3.